# Rank Over Partition By in Oracle SQL (Oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have 4 columns in a table

- Company Part Number
- Manufacturer Part Number
- Order Number
- Part Receipt Date

  Ex.

[image]

I just want to return one record based on the maximum Part Receipt Date which would be the first row in the table (The one with Part Receipt date 03/31/2015).

I tried

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Company Part Number,Manufacturer Part Number 
            ORDER BY Part Receipt Date DESC,Order Number DESC) = 1
```

at the end of the WHERE statement and this did not work.

Comment: Hey Jude, would be great to see a marked answer here if one of them helped you solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytic functions like `rank()` are available in the `SELECT` clause, they can't be invoked directly in a `WHERE` clause. To use `rank()` the way you want it, you must declare it in a subquery and then use it in the `WHERE` clause in the outer query. Something like this:

```
select company_part_number, manufacturer_part_number, order_number, part_receipt_date
from   ( select t.*, rank() over (partition by...  order by...) as rnk
         from   your_table t
       )
where  rnk = 1
```

Note also that you can't have a column name like `company part number` (with spaces in it) - at least not unless they are enclosed in double-quotes, which is a very poor practice, best avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your help. This worked. Have one more question though. For reporting reasons I just have to return the dd/mm/yyyy alone from the Part Receipt Date column ignoring the time part. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Jude92 - Instead of including `part_receipt_date` in `select`, include `to_char(part_receipt_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. Only do this for the final report though, not for any intermediate results.

Answer (score 4):

This would seem to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by partreceiptdate desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: The OP partitions by `company_part_number` and `manufacturer_part_number` in his attempt, did you notice that?

Comment: @mathguy . . . I think reading the question is VERY clear:  "I just want to return one record based on the maximum Part Receipt Date which would be the first row in the table".  Window functions are overkill for this operation.

Comment: So it doesn't occur to you that the OP showed a simplified input, when in fact he has several different company part numbers and manufacturer part numbers for which he is trying to get the most recent part delivery? Seriously?

Comment: @mathguy . . . The OP is free to comment and elaborate on any answers (or comments).  This is the simplest solution to the specific question that s/he asked.  I see no reason to complicate it.  I certainly don't presume things not in the question and then downvote other users based on that.

Comment: Typical answer for a newbie who has been on this site for three months. Surprising coming from you. Whatever.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your help. This worked. Have one more question though. For reporting reasons I just have to return the dd/mm/yyyy alone from the Part Receipt Date column ignoring the time part. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Jude92 . . . To get just the date, you can use `trunc()`.  To format the date in a particular way, you can use `to_char()`.